# Announcement list web part

Tags: list, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I would like to create an announcement list webpart that shows the information like in this image I found googling:

[image: Announcement web part]

Information is being shown in a column style, date, title and body, instead of the regular table layout that comes out of the box (shown in the links webpart under News).

Is it possible to do this without development or SharePoint Designer?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is definitely possible using SharePoint Designer 2010.

You need to understand How SharePoint renders the data of a list. It is all the magic of XSLT which transforms an XML data into an HTML document.

You can customize this XSLT to suit your needs and modify the render pattern of the list data.

You can start from here:

`How to: Customize the Rendering of a Field on a List View`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff606773(v=office.14).aspx

http://maulikdhorajia.blogspot.in/2011/06/sharepoint-2010-customizing.html

Comment: Thank you for your message. Unfortunately, I cannot use SharePoint designer or development.

Comment: Then, I think your best bet is to try out content query webpart and try out different available styles in it.

Comment: I am trying that approach. However, these styles need to be in the Style Library that I do not have available in my space, so I guess that only SharePoint administrators can manage that information.

Comment: You should have site owner permission